# SQL view to get records that don't match the JOIN condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, sql-view

I have been trying to get my head around this but not yet found a solution. I am dealing with a SQL view whose results are based on certain conditions. My SQL View is as below

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vAeoiCaseClose]
AS
SELECT  CaseReference, s.AccessNumber
FROM    dbo.AeoiSdtTemp s
JOIN AeoiCaseManagement c on c.AccessNumber = s.AccessNumber
JOIN AeoiCaptureLog a on a.AccessNumber = c.AccessNumber
WHERE   AscertainMethodId IS NOT NULL
AND c.StatusCode = 15 AND a.StatusCode IN (6, 13, 15) 
AND DATEDIFF(dd, s.LastModifiedDate, GETDATE()) <= 80 AND DATEDIFF(dd, a.LastModifiedDate, GETDATE()) <= 80
AND (
   (AscertainMethodId = 1 AND ExtendedStatusId = 1) 
OR (AscertainMethodId = 2 AND ExtendedStatusId = 1)
OR (AscertainMethodId = 2 AND ExtendedStatusId = 4)
OR (AscertainMethodId = 3 AND ExtendedStatusId = 1)
OR (AscertainMethodId = 3 AND ExtendedStatusId = 4)
OR (AscertainMethodId = 4 AND ExtendedStatusId = 1)
OR (AscertainMethodId = 5 AND ExtendedStatusId = 1)
OR (AscertainMethodId = 5 AND ExtendedStatusId = 4)
    )
GO
```

I have to add another condition, so those records are also avaialble as result of the view.

**Condition:**

In some cases there might be 2 records in **dbo.AeoiSdtTemp** with same `(AccessNumber)` but different `(AscertainMethodId)` , in this case the record won't be available in **AeoiCaptureLog** table, But i need those as part of the result of the view.

Please suggest. Appreciate help.

Example:

**dbo.AeoiSdtTemp**

- (AccessNumber)   - 1111   (AscertainMethodId) - 3  StatusCode = 15
- (AccessNumber)   - 1111   (AscertainMethodId) - 5  StatusCode = 11

**dbo.AeoiCaptureLog**

- NO RECORD

**dbo.AeoiCaseManagement**

- (AccessNumber)   - 1111   (AscertainMethodId) - 3  StatusCode = 15

Comment: Have you tried left join instead of i.e left JOIN AeoiCaptureLog a on a.AccessNumber = c.AccessNumber

Comment: @Fact  for the existing conditions in the view i certainly need the record in all 3 tables, but i also need an exception  condition were record is not available in AeoiCapturelog.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty starting point without testing: Use a second alias (s1 and s2 instead of s, or s and s1) to join the dbo.AeoiSdtTemp table to itself using the s.AccessNumber, like so:

```
...
FROM    dbo.AeoiSdtTemp s1
...
JOIN    dbo.AeoiSdtTemp s2 ON (
            s2.AccessNumber = s1.AccessNumber
            AND s2. AscertainMethodId != s1. AscertainMethodId
        )
...
```

Also, do a review of LEFT vs RIGHT and INNER vs OUTER joins, which will help you determine the way that the clause above will affect your resulting data.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but if I use the self Join on AeoiSDT along with the Joins on AeoiCaptureLog  and AeoiCaseManagement, it wont return the record as it wont be available in AeoiCapturelog

Comment: Are you able to provide sample data for the two possible cases?  Also, your sample VIEW does not make it clear which fields are in which tables to begin with.